# Unable to resolve gms tapandpay dependancy in Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have one sdk which has dependancy of below module:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tapandpay:16.0.2'`

While building it's gives below error:
`ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tapandpay:16.0.2`

This is my top level gradle script contains:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are meant to download a folder including the .aar from the website and place it all in your androidSdk folder as Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms. I was working with gradle 4.1 but since I switched to gradle 5.1.1 it can't find it

Comment: @Youyougoslave did you manage to fix it?